# Tachyonic instabilities

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, cosmological-inflation, modified-gravity, tachyon

How to find tachyonic instabilities for some parameter ranges in the $f(R)$ gravity model? I have tried to find the parameter ranges for exponential $f(R)$ model, Starobinsky $f(R)$ model and Tsujikawa $f(R)$ gravity model, but could not find any proper ranges which lead to tachyonic instabilities
.